# Post HttpPostedFileBase To Remote Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to post HttpPostedFileBase to remote webApi.

```
public bool CreateClaimAttachmentCustomerDoc(ClaimAttachmentSimple attachment, HttpPostedFileBase hpf)
{    
            string jsonStrAttchment = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(attachment);
            string jsonHpf = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(hpf);

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiBaseUrl"] + "claim/CreateClaimAttachmentCustomerDoc?attachment=" + jsonStrAttchment + "&hpf=" + jsonHpf);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";

            WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
            {
                if (webStream != null)
                {
                    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream))
                    {
                        responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Getting the following error.

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error getting value from
>   'ReadTimeout' on 'System.Web.HttpInputStream'.'
>   InvalidOperationException: Timeouts are not supported on this stream.

Comment: You set method as `POST` but in fact you send your request in a `querystring`. Most browsers and servers have restrictions on the `URL` length in `GET` request.